# Homestead 2.0 - Trouble adding new L5 site

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, homestead

I'm having a lot of trouble trying to add a new L5 site to homestead. I've got two laravel 4.2 sites running. I've added it to the homestead.yaml, added it to my hosts file and provisioned the vm. Iv'e also ssh'd in and run the serve command.

Even tried destroying the vm and re creating it, which would look like a hosts file issue, but if I ssh in and ping newsite.dev it just times out, where as I can ping oldsite.dev.

I can see the site in /var/nginx/sites-available and /var/nginx/sites-enabled.

Running OSX 10.11.1

Does anyone have any suggestions for further debugging?

Thanks, Charlie

**For reference: my Homestead.yaml**

Both the prism.app and windsong.app sites work with no issue, the shop.app is the problem.

```
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 2
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: "~/dev/apps/www"
      to: "/home/vagrant/apps"
      type: "nfs"

sites:
    - map: prism.app
      to: "/home/vagrant/apps/prism/public"
    - map: windsong.app
      to: "/home/vagrant/apps/windsong/public_html"
    - map: shop.app
      to: "/home/vagrant/apps/shop/public"

databases:
    - homestead
    - prism
    - windsong
    - shop

variables:
    - key: APP_ENV
      value: local
```

Comment: I know you know, but it sounds like a hosts file issue. can you post your `hosts` file up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding

```
shop.app 192.168.10.10
```

to your `/etc/hosts`

Also try running `sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder` in your terminal.

Comment: WOW... because you wrote DOMAIN IP  instead of IP DOMAIN, it made me double check my hosts file and after all that (literally hours of debugging) I just saw my error..... ip in hosts was 192.186.10.10.... Thank you so much! I was going crazy...